# Add-on for inserting Google Map embed?

Tags: channel-entries, add-on, google-maps-for-ee

I'm wondering if there's an add-on out there-- or perhaps an altogether different approach-- for allowing a user to easily insert a Google map embed (`iframe`) based on an address? I have a channel dedicated to "favorite destinations" with fields for name, address, etc. and currently prompt the user to copy and paste the corresponding Google map embed code into the appropriate field when publishing an entry. This approach is of course not ideal, as there is considerable margin for error with a user inputting actual markup, and I'm trying to figure out the easiest approach here to simplify the user's process.

I see that Objective HTML has the [Google Maps for ExpressionEngine](https://objectivehtml.com/google-maps/features) add-on, but I'm not sure if it allows for this sort of functionality--i.e. auto-generating the iframe embed code corresponding to a specific address and inserting it into the proper `div` in a template?

Thanks for any guidance here.

Comment: Also see these results at https://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=google+map&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is yes Google Maps for EE would be able to do exactly what you want to do.

You would add the included fieldtype to your channel which would allow a user to enter the address and find the correct location. Then in your template you would need to add the appropriate template tags to achieve what you are looking for.

You can see a bunch of examples [here](https://objectivehtml.com/google-maps/examples)

Comment: Thanks Justin-- I've looked at the examples, and I'm still not quite what the appropriate template tags would be for my specific purpose, i.e. generating the appropriate embed code; would you be able to provide any more specific guidance here?